# there was an error while trying to automatically provision the project: 'invalid request,service mapping to the requested url is not available'

Tags: xamarin, provisioning

I'm trying to develop Xamarin app using visual studio and iOS iPad on windows but getting this error.i.e there was an error while trying to automatically provision the project: 'invalid request,service mapping to the requested url is not available'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy your project to a physical device for testing?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. It occurs in a Xamarin Forms iOS project, under **Project** -> **Properties** -> **iOS Bundle Signing** -> **Automatic Provisioning**. From here I select my Team and the above error appears. What's going on?